# How can I send data (or the entire model if possible) from view to the "Update" action in controller without using form?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

My Index.cshtml view:

```
@addTagHelper *,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using Assignment3.Models
@model TblMatHang


    <form id="frm" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post">
        Product Code: <select name="maHang" onchange="onChange()">
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.MatHangs)
            {
                @if (ViewBag.SelectedID == item.MaHang)
                {
                    <option value="@item.MaHang" selected>@item.MaHang</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@item.MaHang">@item.MaHang</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
    </form>


    Product name
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="FilterName" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Fname" asp-for="Tenhang" />
        <button type="submit">Filter by Name</button>
    </form>

    Unit
    <input type="text" asp-for="Dvt" />
    <br />

    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="FilterPrice" method="post">
        Old Price
        <input type="number" name="oldP" asp-for="Gia" /> --> New
        <input type="number" name="newP" />
        <button type="submit">Filter by Price</button>
    </form>

    Image link
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="FilterImage" method="post">
        <input type="text" asp-for="Image" name="Image" />
        <button type="submit">Filter by Image</button>
    </form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Update" method="post">
                <button type="submit">UPDATE</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
                <button type="submit">RESET</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function onChange() {
        document.getElementById("frm").submit();
    }
</script>
<br />
Danh sach mat hang:

<form id="frm" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Ma Hang</td>
            <th>Ten Hang</th>
            <th>DVT</th>
            <th>Gia</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.MatHangs)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.MaHang</td>
                <td>@item.Tenhang</td>
                <td>@item.Dvt</td>
                <td>@item.Gia</td>
                <td>@item.Image</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</form>
```

HomeController:

```
using Assignment3.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Assignment3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            using (MyOrderContext context = new MyOrderContext())
            {
                var list = context.TblMatHangs.ToList();
                ViewBag.MatHangs = context.TblMatHangs.ToList();
                return View();
            }            
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string maHang)
        {
            using (MyOrderContext context = new MyOrderContext())
            {
                ViewBag.SelectedID = maHang;
                ViewBag.MatHangs = context.TblMatHangs.ToList();
                TblMatHang m = context.TblMatHangs
                    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.MaHang == maHang);
                return View(m);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult FilterName(string fname)
        {
            string search = fname;
            using (MyOrderContext context = new MyOrderContext())
            {
                ViewBag.MatHangs = context.TblMatHangs.ToList();
                TblMatHang m = context.TblMatHangs
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Tenhang.ToLower().Contains(search));
                ViewBag.MatHangs = context.TblMatHangs
                    .Where(x => x.Tenhang.ToLower().Contains(search)).ToList();
                return View("Index", m);
            }
        }

        public IActionResult FilterPrice(float oldP, float newP)
        {
            float oldPrice = oldP;
            float newPrice = newP;
            using (MyOrderContext context = new MyOrderContext())
            {
                ViewBag.MatHangs = context.TblMatHangs.ToList();
                TblMatHang m = context.TblMatHangs
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Gia > oldPrice && x.Gia < newPrice);
                ViewBag.MatHangs = context.TblMatHangs
                    .Where(x => x.Gia > oldPrice && x.Gia < newPrice).OrderBy(x => x.Gia).ToList();
                return View("Index", m);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Update(TblMatHang m)
        {
            using (MyOrderContext context = new MyOrderContext())
            {
                m = new TblMatHang
                {

                };
                return View(m);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult FilterImage(string image)
        {
            string search = image;
            using (MyOrderContext context = new MyOrderContext())
            {
                ViewBag.MatHangs = context.TblMatHangs.ToList();
                TblMatHang m = context.TblMatHangs
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Image.ToLower().Contains(search));
                ViewBag.MatHangs = context.TblMatHangs
                    .Where(x => x.Image.ToLower().Contains(search)).ToList();
                return View("Index", m);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm intend to update the information of the corresponding product by passing model from Index view to the Update controller, changing its attributes' values, saving changes then returning to view to be shown on the table below.
I've also tried using nested form and javascript but it just didn't work/or generated a lot of unwanted problems.

Sorry for those non-English names.

Comment: Hi @Harry Vo, your view contains multiple record, but you only contains one update button. How do you know which record you need update? Also, you even do not contain any input used to modify the record, do you want to change the value in backend? I think you need explain more details. Normally we suggest you can add a update button for each row. If you want to change in the frontend, suggest you use partial view to display the need updated value with inputs to modify them. If you want to change in the backend, suggest you just pass the id which is enough.

Comment: @Rena sorry for the poor explanation, that Update button is used to update (or insert if not found) all the attributes of this model at the same time based on the textbox's values.

Comment: Hi @Harry Vo, so how do you find the model? Based on multiple textbox's value? And your code use foreach loop, will you get only one record after filtering? And how do you want to update/insert the value? Also based on the filter value?